# Composite key relations in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

I am getting an error

```
error: BookGroupEntry has a foreign key (bookGroupParameterId) that references BookGroupParameter (id) but BookGroupParameter does not have a unique index on those columns nor the columns are its primary key. SQLite requires having a unique constraint on referenced parent columns so you must add a unique index to BookGroupParameter that has (id) column(s).
```

and it completely boggles my mind because I dont have the situation as reported by the error

My BookGroupParameter table is as follows

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "BookGroupParameters",
    primaryKeys = ["id", "parameterId", "bookGroupId"],
    indices = [Index("id")],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Parameter::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("parameterId"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),

        ForeignKey(
            entity = BookGroup::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("bookGroupId"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )]
)
data class BookGroupParameter(
    @NonNull
    var id: Int,
    val bookGroupId: Int,
    val parameterId: Int
) {
}
```

and this is my BookGroupEntry Table

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "BookGroupEntries",foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = BookGroupParameter::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("bookGroupParameterId"),
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )]
)
data class BookGroupEntry(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int,
    var value: String,
    val bookGroupParameterId:Int
)
```

Why is it telling me that my FK in BookGroupEntry is not defined as a PK in BookGroupParameters table?

Answer (score 2):

As for me error message makes sense:

- Index("id") really is not unique index
- "id" column is not the primary key in BookGroupParameter table (since its primary key is composite as you wrote)

To get rid of error you can:

1. To make your index in table **BookGroupParameter** unique:

```
    indices = [Index("id", unique = true)]
```

2. To put your composite primary key of **BookGroupParameter** in **BookGroupEntry**:

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "BookGroupEntries",foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = BookGroupParameter::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("id","bookGroupId","parameterId"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("bookGroupParameterId","bookGroupParameterBookGroupId","bookGroupParameterParameterId"), // changed
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )]
)
data class BookGroupEntry(
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int,
    var value: String,
    val bookGroupParameterId:Int,
    val bookGroupParameterBookGroupId:Int, // added
    val bookGroupParameterParameterId:Int // added
)
```

Comment: Absolutely right. However the error should haven't said that "id" wasnt a primary key.  It could have used some other wordings like you need to specify which PK from the composite is unique.

Thanks bro